# Choosing an appropriate statistical test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I'm a HS student working on an experiment. I've derived the data but now I'm unsure as to what statistical test to use. My experiment is about finding a correlation between the salt concentration of the water and its effect on the length of the plants.

So, the independent variable is a discrete variable (e.g. 1g, 2g, 3g, 4g) and the dependent variable is a continuous variable (10 plants were placed in each salt concentration and apart from length variations between the different concentrations, plants placed in the same concentration also tended to have slight variations in their length for e.g. 6.5cm and 6.3cm).

I thought of using Pearson's correlation however both variables should be continuous which is not the case in my experiment. I don't know if there's any test for one discrete and one continuous variable...Should I consider the independent variable (1g, 2g, 3g, 4g) as "categorical" and do something like ANOVA?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In fact the salt concentration is a continuous variable, though you have controlled it to take discrete values in your experiment: you could have made it any value.  So you may not need to worry about that point.

Comment: What are average plant lengths at each salt level?

Comment: @Henry I see...so I could use Pearson's correlation? however, it isn't considered a formal hypothesis testing tool in my school...so, would it be appropriate to use ANOVA instead, given that the concentration is, to some extent, a discrete variable, therefore categorical?

Comment: Losing the information that $2g$ is (halfway) between $1g$ and $3g$ would not seem a positive step to me

Comment: ..I don't understand?